# Create subclass from superclass initializer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a class `Fruit` and two Subclasses of it `Orange(Fruit)` and `Banana(fruit)`

`Fruit` has an initializer, and I pass some parameters to it. But I don't want it to just create and return a *fruit* necessarily, but based upon the parameters passed to it, to possibly return one of several different *subclasses* of it. For example:

`Fruit(color="yellow")` might return a `Banana` object whereas `Fruit(color="orange")` would return an `Orange`.

How can I do this? I can't do it in `__init__` because the class has already been created. I tried doing it in `__new__` but this wound up messy because my could *would* create the subclass (as expected), but would then wind-up recursivley calling the Superclass's `__new__`.

My workaround has been to just define a `Fruit.create()` static method which creates the appropriate subclass, but this seems a little un-Pythonic.

Is there a "correct" way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses ?

Comment: This seems a little backwards, Fruit is a class so why would you expect it to when initalised return a different class. That seems way more unpythonic than creating a static method that gives you the right fruit class

Comment: @ChrisDoyle If you told someone to give you a Fruit, and they gave you a Banana, would they be wrong? ;-)

Comment: I am not against the factory method of asking from a fruit. what seemed back wards to me was the idea of `var = foo()` where foo is a class but end up returning not an instance of `foo` from its init but an instance of `bar`.  however calling a factory method in fruit to get a subclass makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My point of view is the same as Chris Doyle.

You can use factory mode or your `Fruit.create()`, I think they are very good

If you want to use your ideas, you can do so

```
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Fruit:
            color = kwargs.pop('color', None)
            if color is None:
                raise ValueError("missing keyword argument `color`")
            match color:
                case 'yellow':
                    return Banana()
                case 'orange':
                    return Orange()
                case _:
                    raise ValueError("invalid color: %s" % color)

        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)


class Fruit(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, *, color=None):  # noqa
        pass


class Banana(Fruit):
    pass


class Orange(Fruit):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Fruit(color='yellow'))
    print(Fruit(color='orange'))
```